# Any intellij plugin or software that shows methods usage from class

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, dataflow-diagram

So I have lots of code and It is hard to catch up the flow of it.

I would like to know how I can have a diagram where I can see one class and all the methods it is using from other classes.

I checked code iris and sequence diagram. I see sequence diagram can be useful but it is not user friendly.

Do you know any plugin in Intellij or software which can draw me a graph so I can see which methods are used and I can see the full overview from starting from one class to all other classes methods which are used in that selected class.

It can be like a tree if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just point curson on the function and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
From [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/building-call-hierarchy.html)

Comment: I need as diagram like visually.

Comment: @legend12345 I just tried it, it opens a little tree and you can expand things